# Hubot's github-pull-request-notifier.coffee

Tags: hubot

I recently got a hubot setup for irc and works fine. I'm trying to add [this script.](https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts/blob/master/src/scripts/github-pull-request-notifier.coffee)

I'm not entirely understanding the setup instructions however. The setup instructions read

```
curl -H "Authorization: token <your api token>" \
-d '{"name":"web","active":true,"events":["pull_request"],"config":{"url":"<this script url>","content_type":"json"}}' \
https://api.github.com/repos/<your user>/<your repo>/hooks
```

I don't understand what the `"url":"<this script url>"` refers to. Anyone know?

I'm deploying to heroku if that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Add more explanation for @MikeKusold 's answer

The `curl` command is to create the [github hook](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#create-a-hook), therefore it is set hook to the receiver for the notification.

```
"config": {
  "url": "http://example.com/webhook",
  "content_type": "json"
}
```

The hook is the hubot plugin, so the url path is defined in [that script](https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts/blob/master/src/scripts/github-pull-request-notifier.coffee), see line

```
robot.router.post "/hubot/gh-pull-requests", (req, res) ->
```

Below two lines in that scripts tell you what is after the path, it has parameters `room & type`

```
user.room = query.room if query.room
user.type = query.type if query.type
```

Hubot itself define the port number, it route the path to the plugin as it requested, check this part in [robot.coffee](https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/src/robot.coffee), the default port is `8080`

Therefore the URL is like below

```
http://<your hubot sever>:8080/hubot/gh-pull-requests/?room=<room>&type=<type>
```

Actually you can use `curl` command to test it towards hubot directly first.

Answer (score 1):

`Add <HUBOT_URL>:<PORT>/hubot/gh-pull-requests?room=<room>[&type=<type>] url hook via API`

That is the URL